# How can you strip html tags then limit the amount of characters shown in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can you strip html tags then limit the amount of characters shown after stripping the tags?  I figured out how to do one or the other, but not stripping the tags then limiting the characters shown.

```
var txt = "<div>dasda</div>";
$('#modalload').html(txt).text().substr(0, 2);
```

so in this example it should show "da" instead of showing "`<d`" or having an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var txt = "<div>dasda</div>";  
$('#modalload').html($(txt).text().substr(0, 2));
```

This will work if txt variable is a tag.

Comment: That worked... and was a lot easier than making that long return function!  Easiest to read.   I believe this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to remove html tags from the text first.

```
$('#modalload').html(txt2).text()
  .replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '')
  .substr(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#modalload').html(txt).text(function(index, currentText) {
    return currentText.substr(0, 2);
});
```